# Label to the left of a centered input box

Tags: html, css, label

I want to put the label above the input box to the left, how to do that.
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <form>
                <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
                <p></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no need to capitalize all words in title. It's hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table. By using table you don't need to set any inline CSS.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give margin-right to label.

```
<label for="name" style="margin-right:150px;" >Name:</label>
```